# Support of a Radon probability measure on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Recently by studying some thinks  I came across a Radon measure in a non separable space.
A natural question in my setting is to ask about the support of that measure. Here is my problem,
until now I worked only with measures on separable spaces, and the definition of support in this setting does not fit if we try to transport it to the non separable context.

**More specifically**: let $X=\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ be the space of all bounded sequences of real numbers endowed with the sup norm and $\mu$ a  Radon measure on  the Borel sigma algebra $\mathscr{B}(X)$.

**Questions**

1. How to define support of $\mu$?
2. Is there some general result talking about the support of $\mu$?
   (I meant, results like: $\mu$ cannot have full support, or the support is  separable
   subspace... )

Comment: The usual definition of [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)) of a positive Borel measure $\mu$ on topological space $X$ is the set of all $p \in X$ such that every open neighbourhood of $p$ has nonzero $\mu$-measure; equivalently, the complement of the union of all open sets of $\mu$-measure $0$.  In what way is that unsatisfactory?

Comment: @RobertIsrael  I n that way is not clear to me that the support is a measurable set. In the separable case, suppose that  $\{U_n\}$ is a countable basis for the topology of some topological space $X$; in that setting is clear to me that $X\setminus supp(\mu)=\cup_{k\in F}U_k$ for some set  for some $F\subset \mathbb{N}$. As a consequence $supp(\mu)$ is a measurable set. However in the non-separable case a such argument is not clear to me.

Comment: @Eduardo The support in Robert Israel's comment is closed, hence certainly measurable.